# What is the meaning of "stolen escapes"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Page 23 of *Digital Fortress* by Dan Brown](https://books.google.com/books?id=pfB9VsrdX4IC&pg=PA23&dq="stolen+escapes") mentioned this,

> Their courtship was slow and romantic — **stolen escapes** whenever their schedules permitted...?

I would like to know what is the meaning of "stolen escapes"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from the obvious meaning of taking someone else's property without their permission, to steal can also mean doing something surreptitiously.

> surreptitiously: In a way that attempts to avoid notice or attention; secretively.

In this case, the couple surreptitiously escapes from their surroundings to spend time together.

Comment: Thank you, now it can make sense, is "escapes",here , a noun?

Comment: @BavyanYaldo Yes it is. Here is a good definition for this usage: *An act of breaking free from confinement or control.*